# how to create variables at runtime

Tags: java

I have an byte array that contains the file data. For Khichidi-1 (224-bits), the byte array is divided into N 224-bit blocks, M(1), M(2) ,..., M(N) is there any inbuilt class in java to perform this operation. If there is none like that, then how can we create N no.of variables depending on the no.of message blocks

Comment: What do you mean by Khichidi-1?    
_ is there any inbuilt class in java to perform this operation_: What Operation?

Comment: If you want to create variables like `M(1), M(2) ,..., M(N)` then use array of `M`. ie `<Type> M[] = new <Type>[N];`

Comment: khichidi is the name of the algorithm we are implementing. Operation means storing the N values in the byte array to N different variables

Comment: Is there any method to solve this. Can anyone provide a solution please help me

Comment: That is what arrays are for. Find what the size you need, and create an array of the size needed. See Collections also.

Answer (score 1):

To create classes at runtime with Java you would have to use its reflection capabilities,
see: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

However, I don't think that would help you in this case as the data you describe is simple raw bits of a particular length.  You could divvy the data up into 28-byte chunks in an array of byte arrays.